# Probability combination contains no repetition of letters, part 2

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here's a follow up to my question here: [Probability combination contains no repetition of letters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4240255/probability-combination-contains-no-repetition-of-letters)

> All the combinations of $n$ letters, $r$ together, repetitions permissible, are written down. Find the chance that a combination selected at random will contain no repetition. ($n \ge r$)

The answer in the back of my book is as follows:

> Possible combinations $= R_r^n$. Favorable combinations $=C_r^n$. Chance $= C_r^n \div R_r^n$.

However, I don't understand what $R_r^n$ is, and I couldn't find where the notation $R_r^n$ is introduced in the book. Could anyone explain what $R_r^n$ is, and how $R_r^n$ is the correct choice for possible combinations here?

Comment: What does "r together" mean?

Comment: One can *guess* from the context that  $R^n_r$ means choosing $r$ items from $n$ *with repetition* (**R**), but I have never encountered this notation.

Comment: Have a look to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17108/144421).